# C++ vector erase crashes program

Tags: c++, vector, erase, projectile

My program creates projectiles that move forward, if they go out of certain bounds, they are to be deleted from the vector that they are stored in. The vector stores xcord, ycord, zcord, and their respective directions.

```
int size = bullet.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i+=6)
        {
                float xc = bullet[i];
                float yc = bullet[i+1];
                float zc = bullet[i+2];
                float xd = bullet[i+3];
                float yd = bullet[i+4];
                float zd = bullet[i+5];
                if(xc > 100 || yc > 10 || zc > 100 || xc < -100 || yc < -10 || zc < -100)
                {
                      bullet.erase(bullet.begin()+i, bullet.begin()+i+5);
                      size=size-6;
                      i = i-6;
                }
                else
                {
                     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                     glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id[3] );
                     glPushMatrix(); 
                     glTranslatef( xc+(xd/2), yc+(yd/2), zc+(zd/2));   //x y z coord of sphere
                     glRotatef( 0,0,1,0);
                     glRotatef( -80,1,0,0); 
                     glRotatef( 0,0,0,1); 
                     glScalef( 0.10f, 0.10f, 0.10f); 
                     gluQuadricTexture(quadric,1);
                     gluSphere(quadric,10.0,72,72); 
                     glPopMatrix();
                     glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                     bullet[i] = xc+xd;
                     bullet[i+1] = yc+yd;
                     bullet[i+2] = zc+zd;
                }
        }
```

But when a "bullet" goes out of bounds my program seems to crash. Any ideas?

---

Well changing

```
bullet.erase(bullet.begin()+i, bullet.begin()+i+5);
```

to

```
bullet.erase(bullet.begin()+i, bullet.begin()+i+6);
```

seems to have fixed it

---

For those interested

```
      bullet.push_back(xpos);
      bullet.push_back(0.0f);
      bullet.push_back(zpos);
      bullet.push_back(nxpos);
      bullet.push_back(nypos);
      bullet.push_back(nzpos);
```

happens whenever the mouse is clicked

Comment: When does it crash? Have you debugged it?

Comment: It crashed whenever the sphere left the bounds, and was removed. I figure it was because I was trying to access a position in the vector that didn't exist

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
i < size
```

as your condition, and accessing elements

```
bullet[i] .... bullet[i+5]
```

See anything wrong there? What happens when `i` reaches `size-1`. You'll access `bullet[size + 4]`, right?

Comment: I changed the bullet.begin()+i+5) to bullet.begin()+i+6) and it appears to work. The vector can hold any number of projectiles, each of which take up 6 spaces

Comment: It won't happen as i is incremented by 6 each time

Comment: @TomerArazy: Really? try walking through the code with size == 7

Comment: @PlasmaHH - well, obviously in his code it's always that size%6 =0

Comment: @TomerArazy: How is that obvious? We never see how the code fills the bullets vector, and the OP says "The vector can hold any number of projectiles"

Comment: The moral of the story is - Use iterators, it's simpler

Comment: @AdamKenworthy No, the moral of the story is encapsulate your data. Use a `struct` at least, for `xc`, `yc`, `zc`, `xd`, `yd`, `zd`.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

> Iterators specifying a range within the vector] to be removed:
>   [first,last). i.e., the range includes all the elements between first
>   and last, including the element pointed by first **but not the one
>   pointed by last**.

The problem is that you're deleting only 5 elements instead of 6.